# Regarding Queues in SalesForce(customization)

Tags: queue

*Salesforce-> Manage Users-> Under Queue,*
Queue is created and assign case object to Particular User,Queue Name is displayed in Particular User in List View,but the records which i Have Created,Not Visible to Particular User.
In Sharing Settings My Organization Wide Defaults is Set to private to case Object
Then I have Tried in My List View,Queue Name is there,Inthat Queue I have Created Records ,but the Record is not Visible to Particular User
Cananyone Explain How Queue is Working ,then How to share the Records ,and what is the Difference Between sharing Settings and Queue

Answer (score 1):

You might be running up against this issue..
http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000004750

Change the filter from the "Queue" radio button to the "All Cases" radio button.  Then, under additional filter criteria, set the criteria as follows:
Case Owner Alias equals "Queue Label"